# JavaFX LineChart how to handle NaN, null, or POSITIVE_INFINITY?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I trying to add Double.NaN value as I do in JFreeChart, but JavaFX cant handle it correctly, so it makes this code

```
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i, i%4!=0?a.data.get(i):Double.NaN));
```

absolutely equal to

```
if(i%4!=0) series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i, a.data.get(i)));
```

[how looks Double.NaN and Positive infinity (sry for pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Cs6.jpg)

I searched the internet and only found this, but it is outdated:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092326

Yes, i need a gap in my chart.

**Edit #1** maybe try to add something like this?

```
Iterator<Node> s = chart.lookupAll(".chart-series-line").iterator();
for(int i=0; s.hasNext(); i++) {
    Node n = s.next();
    if(i%4==2) n.setVisible(false);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: In my charts I catch it and set the value to zero or some other value. It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: If i set it to zero or even make something like
`if(i%4!=0)
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i,a.data.get(i)));
else {
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i-.9,0));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i+.9,0));
}
`
it will not help me, cause my chart is autoranging by y-axis without zero

Comment: You said JFreeChart handles it correctly. Why don't you see if their code is available so you can see how they handled it.

Comment: I looked at your link. It suggest the same thing I did, but it also suggested that you ignore the value. Did you try that?

Comment: JFreeChart probably does one of those two things.

Comment: Check this [picture](https://imgur.com/a/MYYOD), where I use serises.add(x,1./0): It will look better, when horizontal lines disappear. Like that
`chart.lookupAll(".chart-series-line").forEach(node -> node.setVisible(false));`

Comment: but this is not correct lookup query, I think

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it works. I am not sure if it will.

```
Set<Node> node = lcMain.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-line-symbol.series0.");    
node.forEach((element) -> {
    System.out.println(element.toString());
});
```